# Azure REST API, Logic App and Slack - How to break Json into several chunks

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, slack

First of all, sorry for the english, this is not my mother tongue.

What i'm trying to do is the following:

1 - Get API REST Azure Advisor Recommendations ( Costwise )
2 - Get the recommendations acordingly to the recommendationtypeID
3 - Post into a channel

The problem is when posting, the logic app fires several recommendations, i would like to make this a little better timed. Like each recommendation sent after an elapsed time or such thing.

I tought i could create a thread to post the results, but logic apps and curl POST seems to not allow this kind of operation and i'm pretty new to this kind of thing.

Is there a way to break each recommendation from the huge JSON, and then post those with a time window between each one? Is there a better way to bring advisor alerts to slack so my costs team would see those in slack?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- You need to enable the Logic app connector to allow chunks that splits large data into chunks

1. Open settings from HTTP connector

[image]

2. Set allow chunks to on

[image]

- Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#set-up-chunking) which describes chunks in Logic apps.

Comment: I dont have that option on my http connector